# Parcel bundler - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production-environment, parceljs

I'm looking for the fast and simple way to build a simple production single page application with parcel, react and GitHub pages. I was trying to bundle the output from `parcel build index.html` with the gh-pages plugin as a raw project but with no success.... The gh-pages project isn't loading as expected. When I do load it instead with use of the base react app cli following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyjarJhVQMM&t=) for ex. it works fine. And after build steps I can see my app is loading on given gh-pages homepage. But I feel like I am missing something with parcel bundle. Can someone point me the right way? 
Thank you a lot!

Comment: This question does not have enough information to provide a proper answer. What error messages are you seeing in the developer console? If your bundled HTML page is having trouble finding the javascript and other assets, maybe you are missing the `--public-url` option.

Answer (score 3):

By default, I believe Parcel references your CSS and JavaScript as root paths, which fail to load when you deploy to GitHub pages which require a relative path.

To build, add `--public-url '.'` to your build command:

```
parcel build index.html --public-url '.'
```

This will change https://user.github.io/my-script.js to https://user.github.io/project/my-script.js